# Running scala tests in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I want to debug a variable in scala `metadata.sparkVersion` in `KMeans.scala` using scala test suits in spark `KMeansSuite.scala`.

[image]

I have set my break point. However when I try to run (Or right click) it, I dont see a `Run` option. How do I fix this?. How should I go about debugging the code.

[image]

Comment: Can you run it via the console? Can you show how you declare the tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please follow the [tutorial](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_intellij). You need Scala plugin if you want Idea to undestand ScalaTest. If it is already done:
Right click on test folder and "Mark directory as"-> "Test Sources Root".

Alternative is to annotate the test with 
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner]) see [here](http://scala-ide.org/docs/current-user-doc/testingframeworks/index.html)
Then the tests will be executed with JUnit

Or you can have JUnit tests

Comment: I already have scala plugin installed. Otherwise would have got a compile time error. I could not make the test run even after making the directory `Test Sources Root`

Comment: Try importing project from maven/gradle or check sbt dependency